# Why there is extra url adding thing? How can I solve this error?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-react

I am trying to deploy a django-react application. I deployed my backend api and it is working perfectly. I tried to deploy my react frontend using netlify. In localhost all this are working perfectly. I fetched the api from my deployment server. But my frontend deployment is not working. It is showing me

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ().

it is trying to fetch the api from it's own url + the api links

[image]

Why there is extra own url adding thing? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: show your code looks like string is getting concatenated somehow

Comment: show your fetch code and your api url.